# My eclipse view is gone

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, workspace

I was trying to install an eclipse plugin. When the eclipse restarted after the installation, I got the following view:

[image]

As you see, my workspace view is gone. The area where I write the code is gone. Console view is gone. It's all white. There is not toolbar to click on. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Edit: I also see the following error on the page. It keeps coming.

[image]

Error details:

[image]

.log file shows this:

```
!SESSION 2014-05-05 18:53:28.765 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\zaid.almahmoud\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-05-05 19:03:36.340

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:03:36.342
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:08:36.482
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:13:36.609
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:18:36.633
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:23:36.666
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:28:36.729
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:33:36.787
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:38:36.843
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-05-05 19:43:36.902
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persistWorkbenchModel(Workbench.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.persist(Workbench.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$44(Workbench.java:1132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$60.runInUIThread(Workbench.java:2736)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: UML 2 eclipse Plugin.

Comment: Try to reproduce the error and post a bug report on the UML 2 bug tracker (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=MDT&component=UML2) if the error persists.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for a more detailed error

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running eclipse with -clean argument.I was facing the same issue after installing the eclipse Perforce plugin in kepler.But the issue is resolved after i closed and started eclipse with -clean argument.

Hope this works for you also.

Regards,
Anudeep.

Answer (score 1):

[Uninstall bad plugin manually](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F)
 There is no mechanism within Eclipse to permanently and physically uninstall a feature and its plug-ins. The process to physically and permanently remove an undesirable feature and its plug-ins is a manual process that should be done when Eclipse is not running. In order to do, you will have to manually remove the files there associated with the feature from theeclipse/features directory and its plug-ins from theeclipse/plugins directory. Be very cautious as to which files you delete, and always have a backup of your Eclipse directory. If you remove the wrong files from these directories, you may have quite some trouble restoring your Eclipse to a stable state.

Answer (score 1):

The install / update went wrong. You can revert the installation by using the p2 director as explained in this wiki post:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Revert_an_Update_or_Installation_with_p2

Since in your case the UI Shows up, you can revert via Menu: *Help > About*

Then select **Installation Details**:

[image]

And in the *Installation Details* window choose the plug-in and **Uninstall** it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the link at the start of Basilevs's answer for more explanation about uninstalling.

If you have no other third party plugins installed, the easiest and cleanest way might be to uninstall MyEclipse and then reinstall it. This won't affect your workspace. If you do this and have other third party plugins installed, you will need to reinstall them.

Note that MyEclipse has some support for UML2, though it hasn't been upgraded in a while. If you want to install other UML2 tools instead, it might be a good idea to uninstall the UML 1/2 support. This can be done from the Help->Choose Components page.